# Is it possible to remove <ul><li> from default category widget?

Tags: categories, widgets, customization

I´m having some difficulty override to default category widgets in my wordpress theme. I created the theme from scratch.

I want to remove the `<ul><li></li></ul>` from categories in the lists. I want to add my own style using `<a href=""></a>` instead

```
<div class="list-group"> 
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">LifeStyle</a> 
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">SmartPhones</a> 
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">Business</a> 
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">Graphic Design</a> 
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">Agriculture</a> 
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">Music</a> 
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">Travel</a>
```

I can override it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really tricky and long question, there is no easy way to do this, as I guess you want to override this core WordPress function from within your theme.

The way to go is a particular case of something [explained here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33207/modify-a-output-of-a-widget), so you can do the following in your `functions.php`.

Create a new class by copying the code from the [original source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/default-widgets.php#L0).  Give it a new name (in this example I will be using `WP_Widget_Categories_Modified`), and start modifying it.

After that you need to *unregister* the original Widget and *register* the new one (so, again, assuming your new class is named `WP_Widget_Categories_Modified`):

```
function replace_default_wp_widgets() {
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Categories' );
    register_widget( 'WP_Widget_Categories_Modified' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'replace_default_wp_widgets', 1 );
```

Now, you have replaced the default class with the new one, which is exactly the same as the original. So you need to start modifying the new class you created.

First of all, delete the `<ul>` and `</ul>` before and after `wp_list_categories` in your new Class (remember you copied the original code).

Since the WordPress original class calls to `wp_list_categories`, which includes the code, the best choice is to add a custom 'walker' to the function.

To do so, also add in your `functions.php` the walker, for instance:

```
class Walker_Categories_Plain extends Walker {
    var $db_fields = array( 'parent' => 'parent_id', 'id' => 'object_id' );  
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= "\n<a href='" . get_term_link( $item ) . "'>" . $item->name . "</a>\n";
    }    
}
```

Then, you need to pass this walker to `wp_list_categories`. To do this, add this argument as this, **before** the call to `wp_list_categories()`:

```
$cat_args['walker'] = new Walker_Categories_Plain;
```

That's it, it should work if I did not forget anything!

The walker can be modified to change the output until you reach your desired code (check the `$output` string).

Now, your theme:

1. Hides the default Category Widget
2. Registers its own Category Widget (which is only used to delete the `<ul>` and to pass the new Walker by default)
3. Creates its custom Walker (may be used anywhere else to modify `wp_list_categories`)

Comment: Thx you for your guide now I can customize default category output successfully.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me `<?php echo the_category(' '); ?>`.It removed ul li then you can style hyperlink using parent div class or id.