# How to edit wordpress widgets?

Tags: widgets

I am developing a wordpress theme which will be sold out to users on some marketplace. I was finding a way to edit Wordpress widget. 

And I found that and from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293443/where-are-wordpress-default-widget-files-or-functions-located/2293494#2293494)  all the code is available in `/wp-includes/default-widgets.php`
If I only wanted to change the title then I will have surely passed a parameter in `register_sidebar()` `before_title` options but the problem is I don't want to only change the title but add images to the recent post (Without Plugin) which requires the modification of the code.
Now my **question** is 'What can be the downsides of editing the wordpress widget files directly?' Will the wordpress update overwrite it or the buyers of the theme will be safe?

Comment: Never modify core files - not only will WP updates overwrite those changes, but you also have no way of knowing what other themes and plugins may be modifying things. It is safer to either extend a widget (which copies it, but lets you modify the copy, so the end user will be able to choose between the core widget and your extended one) or at least unregister the core widget and register your own in its place. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33207/modify-a-output-of-a-widget

Comment: Thanks for your reply WebElaine, I knew what I'm doing is not right for sure. Thats the reason I asked the question as I failed to find an answer like the link you posted. Thanks a lot ! :)